# matching quarterly data to daily data excel

Tags: excel

Given some data that looks like this:

```
date    CAY
1/31/1952   0.02
2/29/1952   0.03
3/31/1952   0.02
4/30/1952   0.03
1/31/1953   0.03
2/28/1953   0.03
3/31/1953   0.03
4/30/1953   0.02
1/31/1954   0.03
2/28/1954   0.03
3/31/1954   0.03
4/30/1954   0.03
1/31/1955   0.04
2/28/1955   0.03
3/31/1955   0.02
4/30/1955   0.02
1/31/1956   0.01
2/29/1956   0.00
3/31/1956   0.00
4/30/1956   0.00
```

The dates are misleading. Values for the month of January are actually quarterly, meaning I want to have every daily value from 1/31/1952 to 3/31/1952 to be 0.02.

More specifically, where the quarters are the months 1/2/3/4 in my data above:

```
Quarter        Report period    
1              January 1 through March 31
2              April 1 through June 30
3              July 1 through September 30
4              October 1 through December 31
```

Expected output:

```
date        CAY
1/2/1952    0.02
1/3/1952    0.02
1/4/1952    0.02
1/7/1952    0.02
1/8/1952    0.02
1/9/1952    0.02
1/10/1952   0.02
1/11/1952   0.02
1/14/1952   0.02
1/15/1952   0.02
1/16/1952   0.02
1/17/1952   0.02
1/18/1952   0.02
1/21/1952   0.02
1/22/1952   0.02
1/23/1952   0.02
1/24/1952   0.02
1/25/1952   0.02
1/28/1952   0.02
1/29/1952   0.02
1/30/1952   0.02
1/31/1952   0.02
2/1/1952    0.02
...
4/1/1952    0.03
4/2/1952    0.03
...
7/1/1952    0.02
....
11/1/1952   0.03
```

How can this be done easily in excel?

Comment: Quarterly data doesn't heve the granularity of daily data, with what is there, I don't see how you can extract one from the other. Can you post the expected result?

Comment: For the purposes of my research I simply need to have daily data where if the day falls in the range of the quarter I have information for, that day gets that quarter's  value. I will update the OP with expected output.

Comment: is that the minimum or first value for the quarter? You can get the quarter with something like `INT(MONTH(A3)/3)` and use `IF` function to compare the year and quarter of the date above to decide which value to get

Comment: I only have 1 value per quarter, stored as the month. 1/31/1952 is Quarter #1 for 1952, 2/28/1952 is Quarter #2 for 1952, etc. Will that work?

Comment: so your "dates" are not actual dates, but `quarter/day/year` ? Then I guess you will need some kind of a LOOKUP function ..

Comment: Yep, that's how they are stored. I'm not certain because I normally use Access, but I thought lookup functions were for retrieving data between sheets?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` have modes for finding values that are not exact match. For example, `MATCH` can find the index of the first value that is less or greater than certain value.

Comment: The short answer to your question is that you could do it fairly easily with some helper columns or  a VBA solution like the one from @Jeeped.

Answer (score 1):

Run this through the data on Sheet1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dailyData()
    Dim vals As Variant, d As Long, fd As Long, ld As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        fd = DateSerial(Year(Application.Min(.Columns(1))), 1, 1)
        ld = DateSerial(Year(Application.Max(.Columns(1))), 12, 31)
        ReDim vals(1 To (ld - fd + 2), 1 To 2)

        vals(1, 1) = "date": vals(1, 2) = "CAY"

        For d = fd To ld
            vals(d - fd + 2, 1) = d
            vals(d - fd + 2, 2) = .Cells(Application.Match(CLng(DateSerial(Year(d), Int((Month(d) - 1) / 3) + 2, 0)), .Columns("A"), 0), "B").Value
        Next d

        .Cells(1, "C").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
        .Cells(1, "C").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I seem to get this error: Object does not support this property or method. My date column is formatted as a date, and the values as numbers. What's wrong?

Comment: You failed to mention what line the error occurs on but you could try changing `Application.Days(ld, fd) + 2` to `ld - fd + 2` .

Comment: It doesn't seem to tell me what line the error occurs on, but with the changes you suggested it now gives a type mismatch error. My only adjustments to your code was to change "sheet1" to the actual sheet name, which was "quarterly".

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois change Error Trapping to Break In Class Module http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx (in the VBA editor: Tools -> Options -> General)

Comment: Seems like the error is on this line `vals(d - fd + 2, 2) = .Cells(Application.Match(CLng(DateSerial(Year(d), Int((Month(d) - 1) / 3) + 2, 0)), .Columns("A"), 0), "B").Value`

Comment: Hover over `d` when the error occurs. What is the value? Are those real dates in column A?

Comment: `d=41913`, I just checked my data and yes, every value in column A are formatted as dates

Comment: Given your sample data d should be a number between 18,994 and 20,820. 41913 is 01-Oct-2014 so you seem to be missing a 4/30/2014 value in column A.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the dates, enter and select the first date, and Home tab -> Editing -> Fill -> Series... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-of-sequential-dates-aa1c0fa7-c76a-4762-8bc9-46f1691defec

[image]

Then next to the first date try this formula and fill down (adjust `A2` to the cell of the first date, and `quarterly!A:B` to the source range) :

```
=LOOKUP( DATE(YEAR(A2), INT((MONTH(A2) - 1) / 3) + 2, 0), quarterly!A:B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I meant by helper columns - very basic but does work

[image]

In C2

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)*3-2,1)
```

In D2

```
=EOMONTH(C2,2)
```

In E2

```
=D2-C2+1
```

In G2

```
=IF(G1="",1,IF(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,G1)<INDEX($A$2:$E$10,G1,5),G1,G1+1))
```

In H2

```
=IF(G1=G2,H1+1,INDEX($A$2:$E$10,G2,3))
```

In I2

```
=INDEX($A$2:$E$10,G2,2)
```

So Column G contains 91 1's 91 2's 92 3's etc. and is used to index back to the original data.